# How to fix the last element of LineLayout that it does not go beyond the boundaries of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I try make layout with two TextView and one Linear Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="testsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddasdsdfsdfsdf"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="NOT HIDE TEXT"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when the first element has many characters second text is hidding.
[image: Not need]
But I want to do so:
[image: I need]
And when first text is short (or second element may not fill all aviliable area):
[image: Normal mode]
How i can do it? May be i need use RelativeLayout?
Big thanks for your answers!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like below? You just need to add another view that will fill the empty space after "NOT HIDE TEXT" and will look exactly alike.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="testsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddasdsdfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="NOT HIDE TEXT" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ugly but genius solution

Answer (score 0):

```
     To have 10dp of space at left between widgets use
     android:marginLeft="10dp"
    To have 10dp of space at Right between widgets use
     android:marginRight="10dp"

    or you can use android:margin for having 10dp space on all four co-ordinate of the widget.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="NOT HIDE TEXT"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="testsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddasdsdfsdfsdf"/>
</FrameLayout>

which ever Widget will be last in hierarchy will be visible its like stack of widgets.
```

Comment: What for? I want the second element not to shrink and go behind the screen.

Comment: If you want the second layout go behind use <FrameLayout> instead of Relative and LinearLayout they will not work.

Comment: Can you write example?

Comment: i have changed my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="testsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddasdsdfsdfsdf"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="NOT HIDE TEXT"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now both textViews will occupy half the width of screen. Adjust the weight to increase decrease the width.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: No. Here the ratio does not work. I need the second View to occupy all the remaining available space. The width of the first View is not constant

Comment: Then make the first view wrap content and remove the weight and keep weight 1 for the second viee

Answer (score 0):

Use a tableLayout and inside that tableRow.Align one view to parent left and other to layout_alignParentRight. If the value of first view is blank the second view will be aligned to left. And if not it will be aligned to the right of first view.

```
 <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:shrinkColumns="0">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_read"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_read"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_description"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shahin Mursalov is Right but there is no need to take two `LinearLayout` just one will be good enough.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="hrizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kek1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="tegetghrhrebbbbbbbbbbbbgetgetge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-90dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/kek1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:text="NOT HIDE TEXT" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

with long Text

[image]

with Short Text

[image]

Comment: He needs the red one to fill the empty space, not the orange one.

Comment: Still No need to take extra layout.. @Никита Куликов Check out my updated answers

Comment: Updated one is not a solution either. You cannot just assume that the text inside red box will always take less than 90dp space.